# Imprimir datos de una array con foreach en laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hola estoy tramando de imprimir dos objetos que se encuentran en un array, lo único que obtengo es que el ultimo objeto de imprime dos veces y no toma el primero.

```html
foreach ($ingredientes as $key=>$ingrediente) {

            switch($ingrediente['intermedio']){
                case '0': // MATERIA PRIMA
                //$materia_prima=inclca_materia_primas::select('id','nombre_materia','codigo_catalogo','codigo_interno','unidad_medida_id','proveedor_id', 'int_cantidad')->find($ingrediente['materia_prima_id']);

                $salidasmp = stocks_salidas_ordenes_produccion::select(DB::raw('materia_id','codigo_lote as codigo_catalogo'))
                           ->where('order_code', $request->code)
                           ->groupBy('codigo_lote')
                           ->get('materia_id')->toArray();
                //dd($salidasmp);
                $materiaArray = array();
                foreach($salidasmp as $salidamp){
                    $materia_prima =inclca_materia_primas::select('id','nombre_materia','codigo_catalogo','codigo_interno','unidad_medida_id','proveedor_id', 'int_cantidad')->find($salidamp['materia_id']);
                    $materia_prima = $materia_prima->toArray();
                    array_push($materiaArray, $materia_prima);
                }
                foreach($materiaArray as $materia_array){
                        for($i=0;$i<count($materiaArray);$i++){
                            $materia_prima[$i]['id']                = $materia_array['id'];
                            $materia_prima[$i]['nombre_materia']    = $materia_array['nombre_materia'];
                            $materia_prima[$i]['codigo_catalogo']   = $materia_array['codigo_catalogo'];
                            $materia_prima[$i]['codigo_interno']    = $materia_array['codigo_interno'];
                            $materia_prima[$i]['unidad_medida_id']  = $materia_array['unidad_medida_id'];
                            $materia_prima[$i]['proveedor_id']      = $materia_array['proveedor_id'];
                            $materia_prima[$i]['int_cantidad']      = $materia_array['int_cantidad'];  
                        }
                    }
                }
```

En este array tengo estos dos objetos

```
"id" => 1324
"nombre_materia" => "Master MIX dUTP"
"codigo_catalogo" => "V5002 (U+ Mix)"
"codigo_interno" => "00016"
"unidad_medida_id" => "10"
"proveedor_id" => "215"
"int_cantidad" => 76800.0


"id" => 1534
"nombre_materia" => "Tubo Auto-Sustentable 2ml Transparente"
"codigo_catalogo" => "WG60016-T"
"codigo_interno" => "00030"
"unidad_medida_id" => "4"
"proveedor_id" => "217"
"int_cantidad" => 50.0
```

Toma el segundo objeto para imprimir el cual es el id "1534"
Anteriormente imprima bien los dos objetos pero uno de ellos era el incorrecto, ahora que toma los dos objetos correctos solo toma el segundo.

Comment: Tu codigo no es muy entendible, seria bueno que traras de explicar que intentas hacer, ademas indicas que cuando imprimes solo te trae el ultimo, pero en el codigo nunca veo que imprimas algo

Comment: Pero viendo por encima del codigo ```$materia_prima['id'] = $materia_array['id'];``` al hacer eso si intentas entrar a ```$materia_prima['id']``` en cualquier lugar, siempre te devolvera el ultimo resultado, ya que en cada iteración del foreach estarias sobreescribiendo la variable

Comment: Gracias por tu comentarios, eh actualizado la pregunta, $materia_prima['id'] dentro de foreach me regresa el primero objeto pero fuera del foreach me regresa el segundo.

Comment: tienes que inicializar el for en 0, y el count tiene que ser a materia_array, no a la materiaArray

Comment: Pon todo el código y la salida que obtienes _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes.

Comment: Como te sigo indicando, tu posible problema es que estas sobreescribiendo en cada iteracion del foreach la variable  ```$materia_prima['id']```, se supone que para ingresar a los valores del array, o en este caso registrarlos, deberias hacer el registro de la siguiente forma ```$materia_prima[$i]['id'] = $materia_array['id'];``` y el for comenzarlo en 0

Comment: Eh Modificado la pregunta.

Comment: @AlejandroLopez revisa mi respuesta

Answer (score 0):

intenta inicializar el contador en 0.
en la linea donde inicias el ciclo

`for($i=1;$i<count($materiaArray);$i++){`

te quedaria tal que asi

```
for($i=0;$i<count($materiaArray);$i++){
$materia_prima['id'] = $materia_array['id'];
$materia_prima['nombre_materia']    = $materia_array['nombre_materia'];
$materia_prima['codigo_catalogo']   = $materia_array['codigo_catalogo'];
$materia_prima['codigo_interno']    = $materia_array['codigo_interno'];
$materia_prima['unidad_medida_id']  = $materia_array['unidad_medida_id'];
$materia_prima['proveedor_id']      = $materia_array['proveedor_id'];
$materia_prima['int_cantidad']      = $materia_array['int_cantidad'];
}
```

Comment: Gracias, pero me sigue retornando el segundo objeto, originalmente solo quería que el primer foreach me imprima los dos objetos pero solo retorna el segundo.

Answer (score 0):

Siguiente los ejemplos de tu codigo, hay varios problemas, asi que vamos desglozando el codigo para entender que hacer

Primero se da a entender que `$materiaArray` contiene 2 arrays con los indices `0` y `1`

```
//Se crea el foreach
foreach($materiaArray as $materia_array){
                    //dd($materiaArray,$materia_array);
//Para entender este if primero se debe saber que $materia_prima['id'] siempre te va
//devolver el ultimo registro, ya que no estas accediendo a ningun indice de este array
//recuerda que estas recorriendo $materia_array y no $materia_prima
//Asi que este if ya no esta funcionando como debe, debido a que si el ultimo id registrado es 101
//basicamente el sistema esta preguntando si 101 no es igual 1324 o 1534
//y según la logica de tu código eso no deberia ser asi, pero bueno
//suponiendo que algún id de $materia_prima['id'] no coincide con $materia_array['id']
//o en este caso 101 no es igual a 1324 o 1534
                    if($materia_prima['id'] != $materia_array['id']){
//Como no coinciden, devuelve true y aqui hay otro detalle de logica
//En cada iteración $materia[] siempre se va a sobreescribir, por lo tanto
//cuando ingreses a $materia fuera del foreach solo te traera el ultimo resultado registrado
                        $materia = [
                            'id'                     => $materia_array['id'],
                            'nombre_materia'         => $materia_array['nombre_materia'],
                            'codigo_catalogo'        => $materia_array['codigo_catalogo'],
                            'codigo_interno'         => $materia_array['codigo_interno'],
                            'unidad_medida_id'       => $materia_array['unidad_medida_id'],
                            'proveedor_id'           => $materia_array['proveedor_id'], 
                            'int_cantidad'           => $materia_array['int_cantidad']
                        ];
//Ahora una ves hecho el if, comienza el for
//El for deberia iniciar por 0 ya que $materiaArray equivale a 2, sin embargo recordemos
//que $materiaArray tiene el indice 0 y 1
//Si lo dejas asi con el 1, basicamente el sistema pregunta si 1 es menor a 2 puede proceder
//Pero cuando pregunte si 2 es menor a 2, el sistema se detiene porque eso es falso
//En cambio si empiezas por 0 el sistema pregunta 0 es menor a 2? Entonces es true
//1 es menor a 2? es true, y alli termina la iteración del for
                        for($i=1;$i<count($materiaArray);$i++){
//Aqui comienza el mismo detalle, si ahorita aqui mismo haces en echo obviamente te trae
//los resultados como quieres que salga
//Sin embargo, cuando intentes acceder a $materia_prima fuera de aqui te traera el ultimo registro
//Para arreglar esto podrias intentar cambiar todos estos datos
                            $materia_prima['id']                = $materia_array['id'];
                            $materia_prima['nombre_materia']    = $materia_array['nombre_materia'];
                            $materia_prima['codigo_catalogo']   = $materia_array['codigo_catalogo'];
                            $materia_prima['codigo_interno']    = $materia_array['codigo_interno'];
                            $materia_prima['unidad_medida_id']  = $materia_array['unidad_medida_id'];
                            $materia_prima['proveedor_id']      = $materia_array['proveedor_id'];
                            $materia_prima['int_cantidad']      = $materia_array['int_cantidad'];
//Y colocarles $i antes del [] a todos, quedando por ejemplo asi
$materia_prima[$i]['unidad_medida_id']
                    }
                }
```

Sin embargo veo varios problemas de logica, pero veamos si esto lo resuelve

Comment: Eh añadido en todos [$i] en las materias primas pero aun así me regresa el ultimo. cuando pongo break dentro del foreach es el unico momento donde me retorna el primero pero el segundo ya no.

Comment: aja pero y como estas imprimiendo los resultados?